# Show value of Google column chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have a column chart using Google Visualization.

[image]

Right now, in order for me to see each value, I have to hover on each graph to see the value. Example, `2.82 kbps`

I want to show all my value somewhere either on the top of each graph or inside the graph.

How can I show something like that ?

Any hints on that will be much appreciated !

Comment: maybe combine with a google [table](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) chart...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should look into annotations.

The column chart documentation has a cover of it [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#labeling-columns).

Either you add annotation columns to your `DataTable`, annotation for column 1 should be at the index right after, or you can create a view and `stringify` the source column.

```
view.setColumns([0, //The "descr column"
1, //Downlink column
{
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1, // Create an annotation column with source column "1"
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
}]);
```

The annotation is as standard for column charts placed at the top inside of the column.

[Here is my play-around-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/rekso9t6/)

Comment: Your fiddle is much more clear than their documentation.  No offense Google, love your charts!

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: Google has changed the way you're supposed to load their library since 2015.

I've updated the fiddle and seems to be working fine again :)