# Display unit next to value in column

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

So i've been learning that I can use annotations in order to display the columns value inside a column.

```
view.setColumns([0, //The "descr column"
1, //Downlink column
{
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1, // Create an annotation column with source column "1"
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
}]);
```

[image]

I would like to be able to display a unit after each value in the columns.
For example an % ' sign.
Does anyone know how to do this?

(I use a fiddle from another question here on SO,
[Show value of Google column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922876/show-value-of-google-column-chart))

http://jsfiddle.net/bald1/10ubk6o1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use google's [`NumberFormat`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) class to format the `data` before drawing the chart

the `'stringify'` calculation formula will use the formatted value by default

the `format` method on `NumberFormat` takes two arguments:
1) the data table to be formatted
2) the column index of the column to be formatted

```
var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  pattern: '#,##0',
  suffix: '%'
});
formatNumber.format(data, 1);
formatNumber.format(data, 2);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Descr', 'Downlink', 'Uplink'],
    ['win7protemplate', 12, 5],
    ['S60', 14, 5],
    ['iPad', 3.5, 12]
  ]);

  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0',
    suffix: '%'
  });
  formatNumber.format(data, 1);
  formatNumber.format(data, 2);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, //The "descr column"
  1, //Downlink column
  {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1, // Create an annotation column with source column "1"
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  },
  2, // Uplink column
  {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 2, // Create an annotation column with source column "2"
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  }]);

  var columnWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: view
  });

  columnWrapper.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note**: I realize the example provided is from another question but just so you know...

recommend **not using** `jsapi` to load the library, according to [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will also change the `load` statement to...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Im gonna make it work with my chart.