# iccube reporting : How to show values inside columns in a google chart widget

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, iccube-reporting

In previous releases of iccube reporting, I was able to display values inside columns in a google visualization chart. 
Functionality was added by iccube (since Rev. >= 4693) in proper support to configure it for: Column, Bar and Line charts. 
We could find it in the data render configuration (Annotation Expression).

I don't know for how long the functionality disappeared, but it's not available anymore in current release.

I saw an interresting post on this ([Show value of Google column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922876/show-value-of-google-column-chart)) but do not know how to integrate this inside iccube reporting tool.

Will icCube reintegrate this function?  How can I do it myself if not ?

Comment: Right now we can do nothing in reporting, no workaround, so we can only add this feature in the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IcCube re-introduced the Annotation functionality in their reporting V6.8.3.  Thanks!